# how do i get access to the list in map for ElevatedButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, button, maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THaB8.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba4ld.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxY0x.png)

im new to the mobile development can anyone pleased tell me where did i do wrong?
im trying to access to the list inside the map

Comment: Please put your code in the question preferably code that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map is a function, not a Widget. But you can fix it by using ListView.builder like it :

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: questions[_questionIndex]["Questionanswers"].length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Answer(_quess, questions[_questionIndex]["Questionanswers"][index]);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

List of map can be accessed as questions[i]["questionText"]

Comment: Thanks ,but Ive already done that. im mapping a list to a widget.  body: Column(children: [
          Question(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']),
          questions[_questionIndex]['Questionanswers'].map((answer) {
            return Answer(_quess, answer);
          })

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).